# Where are the current kernel build options stored?

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling

Is there a way to know if the kernel was compiled with a certain option activated (i.e. `CONFIG_PROC_EVENTS=y`) without having to pull out the kernel sources package and looking in the config file?

Answer (score 42):

If you look through your `/boot` directory you'll notice these files:

```
$ ls -l /boot/|grep config
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   109919 Oct 21  2011 config-2.6.35.14-100.fc14.x86_64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   109919 Oct 27  2011 config-2.6.35.14-103.fc14.x86_64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   109919 Nov 23  2011 config-2.6.35.14-106.fc14.x86_64
```

Notice what version of the Kernel you're using:

```
$ uname -r
2.6.35.14-106.fc14.x86_64
```

If you `grep` through the appropriate "config-`uname -r`" file you can see what options the Kernel was built with:

```
$ grep CONFIG_PROC_EVENTS= /boot/config-`uname -r`
CONFIG_PROC_EVENTS=y
```

#### References

- [How To Check What Kernel Build Options Enabled In The Linux Kernel?](http://www.walkernews.net/2008/11/21/how-to-check-what-kernel-build-options-enabled-in-the-linux-kernel/)

Comment: That's true in Debian based distros, but may not be true in others, i.e. Arch Linux.

Comment: @ntrrgc - I can't confirm for ArchLinux, but it's that way for RedHat, Debian, & Ubuntu. These 3 distros cover *most* of the *nix world. If someone has a ArchLinux distro can you please confirm this approach?

Comment: I use Arch Linux and I can confirm this does not work in Arch Linux.

Comment: @slm this isn't even true for Ubuntu, at least Kubuntu. I just checked — the only thing I have in `/boot/` is `grub` directory.

Comment: @slm perhaps are these configs a part of some package? Then it would be enough to list files of that package.

Comment: @Hi-Angel - this is a 2+ year old question and the output I showed was from a Fedora 14 system which at the time was how most distros that make use of grub worked. Things have changed now with grub2.

Comment: Hm, I found a pretty interesting thing — I actually found where the file supposed to be with `dpkg -S "config-3"`. And this is… `/boot/config-3.13.0-66-generic` *(well, one of the files)*. However the directory doesn't contain them. Weird…

Comment: Checked with Ubuntu 16.04 and it works

Comment: Not existing such files on Ubuntu nor Kali for RaspBerry.

Comment: These files don't exist for Raspbian, either. There is a /boot/config.txt with an entirely different function.

Answer (score 28):

Kernel options can be found in `/proc/config.gz`.

```
zgrep CONFIG_PROC_EVENTS= /proc/config.gz
```

if the kernel was compiled with `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC=y`. If the kernel was compiled with `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC=m`, then it may be necessary to first `modprobe configs`.

Comment: This did not work for me on any of the distros that I had available: Debian, RedHat based, nor Ubuntu. These are all stock systems so I don't think this approach is that useful unless you built your kernel yourself or your particular distro provides it.

Comment: In distro kernels, the IKCONFIG option may be enabled only as a module. Try to `modprobe configs` and check if /proc/config.gz shows up.

Answer (score 5):

If your kernel was build with `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC`, you can find the configuration listed in `/proc/config.gz`

```
zless /proc/config.gz
```

Debian and Redhat based kernel packages generally install a `config-$version` file in `/boot`,

```
less /boot/config-$(uname -r)
```

In Debian you can also find the default options in `kernel-package`'s `./kernel/Config/config` as well as architecture specific configuration options in `./kernel/Config/`.

```
mkdir /tmp/k
cd /tmp/k
apt-get source kernel-package
find . -path '*/kernel/Config/*' -type f
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo find / -xdev -name .config`(-xdev keeps it on one filesystem)

Generally it will be under `/usr/src/some-specific-kernel-header-version/.config`

Just read it as any text, search with grep, or to see how two versions differ `diff -y -suppress-common-lines /path/linux2.6-r3/.config /path/linux2.6-r4/.config`

Comment: Well, dangit. Someone gave Max a -1, but out of all the methods here, it worked on my RHEL7 machine. So, I have no choice: +1. I found my file at `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64/.config`

Comment: @MikeS I think I was on Debian at that answer date, but I was using CentOS7 not long before.